# JavaScript RandomNumbers

Tags: javascript

I'm still rather new to coding and was looking for a solution to random numbers

Would anyone be able to explain how this sort of code works?
I think have some idea of how it works, it's using Math.random to store 6 six random numbers within an array. Then prints out the 6 Unique numbers.

```
var arr = []
while(arr.length < 6) {
var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.Random()*100)
if(arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
}
document.write(arr);
```

Many Thanks

Comment: What do you not understand? What line[s]

Comment: Then P? Looks like you got cut off there.

Comment: Specifically its guaranteeing 6 unique random numbers by using indexOf to see if the current number has already peen pushed into the array.

Comment: This, as is, doesn't work. `Math.Random()` should be `Math.random()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = []
```

create an empty array

```
while(arr.length < 6) {
```

while the length of the array is less than 6 characters

```
var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*100)
```

create a variable called `randomnumber` with a value of a random number between 1 and 100 (math.ceil rounds the generated number up to the nearest whole number)

```
if(arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
```

`indexOf` will return a number greater than -1 if it exists in the array, so if the random number doesn't already exist in the array, then

```
  arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
```

add the random number to the array in the `arr.length` position (I guess this guarantees that the random number will be added to the end of the array)

```
}
```

close the if statement

```
document.write(arr);
```

write the array to the document